# How do I impute clustered data that is not time-series data?

Tags: panel-data, data-imputation, multiple-imputation

The goal of my research is to understand whether MRI imaging characteristics can predict tumor pathology. The data consists of resected tumor samples, with multiple samples per patient. On the MRI, we can draw precisely where those samples were taken. We have multiple kinds of MRI per patient - anatomic, diffusion, and perfusion. An example of my data might look like this, where x is a number and NA represents a missing value, and MRI imaging parameters from that sample are indicated by .mri:

```
| patient ID | sample ID  | anat.mri.1 | anat.mri.2 | diffu.mri.1 | diffu.mri.2 | perf.mri.1 | perf.mri.2 | path.outcome |
|------------|------------|------------|------------|-------------|-------------|------------|------------|--------------|
| patient 1  | sample 1.1 | x          | x          | NA          | NA          | x          | x          | 1            |
| patient 1  | sample 1.2 | x          | x          | NA          | NA          | x          | x          | 1            |
| patient 1  | sample 1.3 | x          | x          | NA          | NA          | x          | x          | 0            |
| patient 2  | sample 2.1 | x          | x          | x           | x           | NA         | NA         | 1            |
| patient 3  | sample 3.1 | x          | x          | x           | x           | x          | x          | 1            |
| patient 3  | sample 3.2 | x          | x          | x           | x           | x          | x          | 1            |
| patient 4  | sample 4.1 | x          | x          | x           | x           | NA         | NA         | 0            |
| patient 4  | sample 4.2 | x          | x          | x           | x           | NA         | NA         | 0            |
```

So there are a few problems with missingness here: 
1. If a sample from a particular patient has missing diffusion data, it is much more likely that other samples from that patient also have missing diffusion data. 
2. If a sample from a particular patient has one missing diffusion parameter, it is very likely to have another missing diffusion parameter.

I'd like to create a model which accounts for multiple samples per patient, i.e. a mixed effect with patient ID as the group identifier. However, I'd like to use all available data and impute.

I believe it is clear that my data is not MCAR. However, MAR states that the probability distribution of missingness indicators might depend on the observed values, but not on those that are missing. I believe this to be true in the case for my data, since values are no more likely to be missing depending on the missing value. The reason for missingness is whether that MRI sequence was taken at that particular moment in time, which is random.

I'm essentially wondering if I'm understanding this correctly, and whether moving forward with MI using MCMC is valid in my case.

If so, is there an implementation in R that you would recommend?